# How do I create a transparent non-modal dialog with a frame in Qt that is contained within the main application window and can contain QPushButtons

Tags: qt, widget

I would like to create a fixed size floating transparent dialog that can be moved, minimized and closed that can contain QLabels, and QPushButtons and is contained to the main window.  I've tried using a QDockWidget as a container for a QTableWidget but I couldn't make it transparent, just turned black.  I also tried using a QWidget with a QMdiArea but the background isn't transparent.  I'm fairly new to Qt, especially the Ui aspects.  This is a formless C++ application that I'm trying to add this UI element to.  Any direction on how to proceed is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `QDockWidget` together with a `QDialog` (or just a `QWidget` is fine). The transparency can be set using `QGraphicsOpacityEffect` (when the dock is not floating), or `setWindowOpacity()` (when the dock is floating). An example is shown below:

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDockWidget>
#include <QSlider>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    void setDockOpacity();

private:
    QDockWidget dock_widget_;
    QSlider slider_;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QDialog>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

#include <QGraphicsOpacityEffect>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    this->setStyleSheet("QMainWindow"
                        "{"
                        "   background-color: pink;"
                        "}");

    QDialog *dialog = new QDialog(this);
    dialog->setStyleSheet("QDialog"
                          "{"
                          "    border: 2px solid red;"
                          "    background-color: green;"
                          "}");

    QGraphicsOpacityEffect *effect = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(dialog);
    effect->setOpacity(1);
    dock_widget_.setGraphicsEffect(effect);

    slider_.setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
    slider_.setMinimum(10);
    slider_.setMaximum(100);
    slider_.setValue(100);
    connect(&slider_, &QSlider::valueChanged, this, &MainWindow::setDockOpacity);
    connect(&dock_widget_, &QDockWidget::topLevelChanged, this, &MainWindow::setDockOpacity);

    QVBoxLayout *dialog_layout = new QVBoxLayout{dialog};
    dialog_layout->setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
    dialog_layout->addWidget(&slider_);
    dock_widget_.setWidget(dialog);
    dialog->setVisible(true);

    QWidget *widget = new QWidget{this};
    widget->setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid blue;");
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout{widget};
    layout->setContentsMargins(50, 50, 50, 50);
    this->setCentralWidget(widget);

    this->addDockWidget(Qt::TopDockWidgetArea, &dock_widget_);
    this->resize(500, 500);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

void MainWindow::setDockOpacity()
{
    if (dock_widget_.isFloating())
    {
        dock_widget_.setWindowOpacity(slider_.value() / 100.0);
        qobject_cast<QGraphicsOpacityEffect*>(dock_widget_.graphicsEffect())->setOpacity(1);
    }
    else
    {
        dock_widget_.setWindowOpacity(1);
        qobject_cast<QGraphicsOpacityEffect*>(dock_widget_.graphicsEffect())->setOpacity(slider_.value() / 100.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, however the screen underneath the dialog isn't visible.  Would it be possible to make the background transparent so that the objects under the dialog show through?

Comment: I edited my answer. When the dock is floating, `setWindowOpacity()` should be used.